# Mockito testing Rest client

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, resttemplate

I am having a hard time doing unit testing with the Rest client. I am trying to mock the rest call and return a specific object to check its value. But I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute` as an error.

I know that there is a way to use `mockServer` but I think this is helpful only in testing the responses, but not the body.

I am running it with SpringBoot. Here is my code:

Service:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

    private final String url;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public ServiceImpl(@Value("${call.url}") String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public MyObject getMyObject(String param1, String param2) {
        MyObject myObject;

        try {
            myObject = restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyObject.class, param1, param2);
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
            throw new MyObjectException();
        }
        return myObject;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
private Service service;
MyObject found = mock(MyObject.class);

@Mock
RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void() test{
   MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
   myObject.setField(value);

    //Given
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(
        Mockito.anyString(),
        ArgumentMatchers.any(Class.class), 
        Mockito.anyString(), 
        Mockito.anyString()))
    .thenReturn(myObject);

    found = service.getMyObject("param1", "param2");
    //Then
    assertEquals(myObject.getField(), found.getField());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `service.getMyObject("param1", "param2");` you are created a new instance of `RestTemplate`, for that you are making a real call to the method `getForObject` you can implement for example `PowerMock` and do somehting like that:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ServiceImpl.class)
public class ServiceImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private Service service;
    MyObject found = mock(MyObject.class);

    @Mock
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
      MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
      MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
      myObject.setField(value);

      //Given
      whenNew(RestTemplate.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(restTemplate);
      Mockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject(
          Mockito.anyString(),
          ArgumentMatchers.any(Class.class),
          Mockito.anyString(),
          Mockito.anyString()))
          .thenReturn(myObject);

      found = service.getMyObject("param1", "param2");
      //Then
      assertEquals(myObject.getField(), found.getField());
    }
  }
```